# C# Combining 2 lists of different types using Linq [Method syntax]

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 different lists say **MarksAList** and **MarksBList**. Following are the modal class for both

```
   Class MarksA
      Id int
      Name String  
      Mark1 int
      Mark2 int
      Mark3 int
   End Class

   Class MarksB
      Id int
      Name String
      Mark4 int
      Mark5 int
      Mark6 int
   End Class
```

`MarksAList-> List<MarksA>`
`MarksBList -> List<MarksB>`

ID is the unique field in both the class

Sample:

***MarksAList***

```
Id      Name    Mark1    Mark2    Mark3
1       A        60       70       80
2       B        40       50       60
3       C        50       80       50
4       D        50       80       50
```

***MarksBList***

```
Id    Name        Mark4        Mark5        Mark6
3      C           60            70           60
4      D           78            55           88
5      E           60            70           60
6      F           78            55           88
```

Now I have another class. Lets name it ***MarksList*** which is `List<Marks>`. This needs to hold both the record from
MarksA class and MarksB class.

The modal class for ***Marks***

```
  Class Marks
      Id int
      Name String  
      Mark1 int
      Mark2 int
      Mark3 int
      Mark4 int
      Mark5 int
      Mark6 int
   End Class
```

How do I combine MarksAList and MarksB list so that the ***result*** looks like:

```
Id      Name    Mark1    Mark2    Mark3    Mark4     Mark5      Mark6
 1       A        60       70       80       0         0          0
 2       B        40       50       60       0         0          0
 3       C        50       80       50       60        70         60
 4       D        50       80       50       78        55         88
 5       E        0         0        0       60        70         60
 6       F        0         0        0       78        55         88
```

I cannot use join as MarksAList can contain records that are not there in MarksBList and viseversa.
How do I join this using method syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could try left join

Comment: @SelimYıldız I have tried to join both based on code but stuck at a point whereb contains records that a doesnot have.

Comment: @Frenchy How to handle the case for 5 & 6 as per my question if I use left join

Comment: you do the left join 2 times by inverting the A and B..so you have the solution in the answer.. sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `left join`?

```
var first = from a in MarksAList
            from b in MarksBList.Where(x => x.Id == a.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new Marks
            {
                Id = ((int?)a.Id) ?? b.Id,
                Name = a.Name ?? b.Name,
                Mark1 = a?.Mark1 ?? 0,
                Mark2 = a?.Mark2 ?? 0,
                Mark3 = a?.Mark3 ?? 0,
                Mark4 = b?.Mark4 ?? 0,
                Mark5 = b?.Mark5 ?? 0,
                Mark6 = b?.Mark6 ?? 0
            };

var second = from b in MarksBList
             from a in MarksAList.Where(x => x.Id == b.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new Marks
             {
                 Id = ((int?)b.Id) ?? a.Id,
                 Name = b.Name ?? a.Name,
                 Mark1 = a?.Mark1 ?? 0,
                 Mark2 = a?.Mark2 ?? 0,
                 Mark3 = a?.Mark3 ?? 0,
                 Mark4 = b?.Mark4 ?? 0,
                 Mark5 = b?.Mark5 ?? 0,
                 Mark6 = b?.Mark6 ?? 0
             }; 

// it will act same as distinct and remove the duplicated rows
var final = first.Union(second).GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: How to assign code? If I go code = a.Code, what will happen for 5 & 6. a doesnot contain 5 & 6

Comment: @Keerthivel In your case, you should do left join twice, in second time switch the `MarksAList` and `MarksBList` inside the query and for get the final result Union 2 result.

Comment: How many rows will be in that lists? you need to somehow combine that 2 lists, you can use for, foreach or LINQ. you should decide between clean/simple code _LINQ_ or some sort of custom implementation _which will produce more lines of code, which doesn't necessarily provide better performance_

Comment: There will be a maximum of 10000 rows

Comment: Actually, for each class I will get around 10 million records max. I will group those in SQL based on some columns and my final result will be these 10k records. We need not worry about those 10 million records as all those logic is in my view  in sql.

Comment: if you want to win some performance in time you could launch the both left join with the use of thread (parallelism the twice job)  but for 10000 rows i think its relatively quick

Comment: I run some sort of benchmark (simple, using LINQPad), with 10,000 rows in each list, it took ~3s. I think there is better approach to get better performance, using thread _correct way_, as @Frenchy mentioned is one of them.

Comment: @Keerthivel if you get duplicate rows in `final` list, check my answer, I just updated my answer to cover this situation.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Just out of curiosity, what happens if any of the list is null?

Comment: @Keerthivel if by null, you mean actual null value, code won't work and you will get error, but if you mean empty list, there will be no error.

Comment: The simplest fix would be `(MarksAList ?? new List<MarksA>())`, do for both `MarksAList` and `MarksBList` in both queries. _first and second_

Comment: I have already handled it. But the case here is, consider I have one record in MarksAList  and 0 records in MarksBList. In the first query I am getting **`a` is null** error

Comment: Well, figured it out. I had to add the ? operator for `b.Id` and `b.Name`

Comment: I tried with that situation (1 record in MarksAList and 0 in MarksBList), I got following output: `[{"Id":1,"Name":"A","Mark1":60,"Mark2":70,"Mark3":80,"Mark4":0,"Mark5":0,"Mark6":0}]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code can help you

```
public class MarksA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Mark1 { get; set; }
    public int Mark2 { get; set; }
    public int Mark3 { get; set; }
}

public class MarksB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Mark4 { get; set; }
    public int Mark5 { get; set; }
    public int Mark6 { get; set; }
}

public class Marks
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Mark1 { get; set; }
    public int Mark2 { get; set; }
    public int Mark3 { get; set; }
    public int Mark4 { get; set; }
    public int Mark5 { get; set; }
    public int Mark6 { get; set; }
}
```

Main method

```
List<MarksA> marksAs = new List<MarksA>
        {

            new MarksA{ Id = 1 , Name = "A" , Mark1 = 60 ,  Mark2 = 70,Mark3 = 80},
            new MarksA{ Id = 2 , Name = "B" , Mark1 = 40 ,  Mark2 = 50,Mark3 = 60},
            new MarksA{ Id = 3 , Name = "C" , Mark1 = 50 ,  Mark2 = 80,Mark3 = 50},
            new MarksA{ Id = 4 , Name = "D" , Mark1 = 50 ,  Mark2 = 80,Mark3 = 50}
        };

        List<MarksB> marksBs = new List<MarksB>
        {

            new MarksB{ Id = 3 , Name = "C" , Mark4 = 60 ,  Mark5 = 70,Mark6 = 60},
            new MarksB{ Id = 4 , Name = "D" , Mark4 = 78 ,  Mark5 = 55,Mark6 = 88},
            new MarksB{ Id = 5 , Name = "E" , Mark4 = 60 ,  Mark5 = 70,Mark6 = 60},
            new MarksB{ Id = 6 , Name = "F" , Mark4 = 78 ,  Mark5 = 55,Mark6 = 88}
        };

var innerJoinMarks = marksAs.Join(marksBs,
                post => post.Id,
                meta => meta.Id,
                (post, meta) => new { Post = post, Meta = meta }).Select(x => new Marks
                {
                    Id = x.Post.Id,
                    Name = x.Post.Name,
                    Mark1 = x.Post.Mark1,
                    Mark2 = x.Post.Mark2,
                    Mark3 = x.Post.Mark3,
                    Mark4 = x.Meta.Mark4,
                    Mark5 = x.Meta.Mark5,
                    Mark6 = x.Meta.Mark6

                }).ToList();

        var fullOuterExcludingJoin = marksAs.Where(x => innerJoinMarks.All(z => z.Id != x.Id)).Select(x => new Marks
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Mark1 = x.Mark1,
            Mark2 = x.Mark2,
            Mark3 = x.Mark3

        }).Union(marksBs.Where(x => innerJoinMarks.All(z => z.Id != x.Id)).Select(x => new Marks
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Mark4 = x.Mark4,
            Mark5 = x.Mark5,
            Mark6 = x.Mark6

        })).ToList();


        var fullOuterJoin = innerJoinMarks.Union(fullOuterExcludingJoin ).OrderBy(x => x.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this:

```
List<MarksA> listA = new List<MarksA>();

        listA.Add(new MarksA(1, "A", 60, 70, 80));
        listA.Add(new MarksA(2, "B", 40, 50, 60));
        listA.Add(new MarksA(3, "C", 50, 80, 50));

        List<MarksB> listB = new List<MarksB>();
        listB.Add(new MarksB(3, "C", 60, 70, 80));
        listB.Add(new MarksB(4, "D", 78, 80, 90));
        listB.Add(new MarksB(5, "E", 60, 70, 60));
        listB.Add(new MarksB(6, "F", 78, 55, 88));

        var concatList = listA.Join(listB, xA => xA.Id, xB => xB.Id, (xA, xB ) => new { xA.Id, xA.Name, xA.Mark1, xA.Mark2, xA.Mark3, xB.Mark4, xB.Mark5, xB.Mark6 });
```

Comment: It doesn't produce the correct result, based on sample output data.